# How to fetch custom variable value in google analytics data api?

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-code, google-analytics-api

'm using GAPI version 1.3 I have added a custom variable in GA code like this:

```
**_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 1,  'Member', '<?php echo $member_id; ?>, 3]);**
```

And its working fine..

Now I need to fetch the data from GA: so my request to GA is like this:

```
**https://www.google.com/analytics/feeds/data?
ids=XXXXXXXXXXX&
dimensions=ga:customVarValue1,ga:pagePath&
metrics=ga:pageviews,ga:uniquePageviews,ga:bounces,ga:exits&
filters=ga:pagePath=@event_details.php;ga:customVarValue1=2004036442&
start-date=2011-04-20&
end-date=2011-05-04&
max-results=50**
```

I need to fetch data from GA where pagePath=@event_details.php AND ga:customVarValue1=2004036442

But this is not resulting anything...

When I changed the filters in the following why its resulting all the pagePath = event_details.php and its working fine.. filters=ga:pagePath=@event_details.php

But I need get the page path with the particular member ID that is why I used the condition as below: filters=ga:pagePath=@event_details.php;ga:customVarValue1=2004036442&

So any one have idea about this?? Please help..

Comment: Is that GA request a direct copy/paste of what you are sure it's sending, or is it what you think it's sending based on your code? I know that when filtering based on customVarValue you need to manually add "ga:" to the front of it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at the code you posted in Google Docs, I see your problem.
Try using this as your filter.

```
$filter =  'pagePath =@ ' . $filter_text[$tab] . ' && customVarValue1 == 2004036442'
```

The function you are passing $filter to does a cleanup process that escapes any reserved characters with a backslash. Your customVariable is being sent with a slash at the end, which is why it's not returning any matches.

Comment: If you log into the analytics interface, can you verify that the value for that custvar actually exists? Make a custom report to display pagePath and then custVarValue1. When you click the page you want, filter on that value. Perhaps it has something to do with the '&' on the end of your filter. Is that a part of the ID your saving to the custvar? If not, try removing it.

Comment: When we query analytics without custom variable, we are getting all data. That also shows the custom variable values. But when we try to filter one of those values, we are not getting any result...

Comment: Would you mind posting the entire code block that you're using to set the filter and then request the info from Google? Make sure to remove any passwords if they are in there. I'm sure we can resolve this.

Comment: Is there any option to attach zip files to our questions? so that I can add the code here

Comment: There are not, but you can use something like pastebin for large sections of code. http://pastebin.com/

Comment: I have uploaded the files to google doc now. Please see below link.https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=explorer&chrome=true&srcid=0B9PYW9YxoZszYWUzMTcwN2UtNDM3MS00ODU4LWJkYTItMWJhMzhhYjMxMWE0&hl=en_US 

Here I have all the files and also attached our screenshots of the results. Those screenshots are showing how data is showing when we call without custom variables. But when we query custom variables, empty result set is received.

Comment: Using a filter would be your best bet, rather than the dynamic segment that you have set up now (I know you tried using filter previously). First step is to set your segment to NULL. Now, the reason your filter was not working previously is because you were using ; instead of &&. When you pass the filter into RequestReportData function, it automatically converts your string. To get both of those filters functional. See my updated answer for the string you should use for the $filter value.